# What do all the distributions that have the same Gini index have in common?

Tags: econometrics, gini, economics

According to the Wikipedia article about [Income inequality metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_inequality_metrics), Gini index have the next disadvantage:

> As a disadvantage, the Gini index only maps a number to the properties of a diagram, but the diagram itself is not based on any model of a distribution process. The "meaning" of the Gini index only can be understood empirically. Additionally the Gini does not capture where in the distribution the inequality occurs. As a result, two very different distributions of income can have the same Gini index.

So, I want to ask - what do all the distributions that have the same Gini index have in common? (Empirically, they produce the same area under the Lorentz curve, but what does that mean?)

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to caveat, with the same input data (measurement, frequency distribution etc.)

Comment: I did not understand. @psychonomics, can you explain again please?